# How to show additional fields from InfoPath in Document Library?

Tags: workflow, infopath, form, workflow-variable

I have a document library of type InfoPath Forms.

Currently the columns in the list (Library) only showing some of the InfoPath Fields.
I'd like to add the rest of them so they are visible in the library. 
Basically so then I can manipulate them with a workflow. I can't seem to remember where I allowed which columns are visible outside of infopath.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Duh!... 
Here it is. 
Infopath File > Form Options > Property Promotion

[image]
[image]